# Global Array in Grails?

Tags: arrays, grails, controller, global-variables

Is there a way to create an array that is both gettable and settable from any controller in a grails project? Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Why not just make a domain class to represent your array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "gettable and settable" do you mean you want any controller to be able to modify the individual elements of the array or that you want a controller to be able to completely replace the array with another array and have the change visible to other controllers?

The "Grails way" would be to encapsulate the array within a service and access it through that, with the service handling whatever synchronization is required to keep things consistent - and you will definitely need synchronization of *some* kind if you have data that is potentially being mutated by several threads concurrently.  Or store the data in your database and let that handle the transactional updates.

To give a more specific answer I'd need to know what use case(s) this shared array is intended to support.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array and put it in the grailsApplication in bootstrap (or create it lazily). 
In any controllers, you can use that array from the grailsApplication.

Answer (score 0):

You can define/initialize an array in `Config.groovy` then access it using `grailsApplication.config` in any of your controllers.  That's just one way off the top of my head...

**Update**

Here's another simple example using Bootstrap:

**Bootstrap.groovy**

```
class BootStrap {
    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        grailsApplication.config.myArray = []
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

**Some Controller**

```
class TestController {

    def addItem() {
        grailsApplication.config.myArray << "Value ${grailsApplication.config.myArray.size()}"
        render grailsApplication.config.myArray
    }
}
```

You'll need to take care using this approach though.  Groovy uses ArrayList by default which is not thread safe and is prone to concurrent modification exceptions.  If you need to have concurrent execution you'll need to either wrap your adds/deletes in synchronized methods or publish asynchronous events with an event handler or something like that.